# Unrecognized Command running PlistBuddy through Azure DevOps build definition

Tags: macos, azure-devops, plist

I have a Command Line step in my build definition which runs the PlistBuddy cli tool. I've verified that the PlistBuddy is installed and exists in the specified dir, but I'm still getting an error. Is there something that I could possibly be missing here?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Locally the PlistBuddy client worked fine. Seems the version running on the server didn't like the single quotes around the command. What ended up working was:

```sh
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Delete :NSAppTransportSecurity:NSExceptionDomains" Info.plist
```

Comment: Yes, you definitely need single or double quotes after `-c` around the command and arguments or things get stupid.

Answer (score 1):

It's running the tool. The tool is outputting an error message of "Unrecognized Command". Review the tool's command line syntax and update it accordingly. It helps if you run the command locally first and validate that it works outside the context of a pipeline.